# How do I repeat a texture with GLKit?

Tags: opengl-es, ios

I am using GLKit in order to show textures on my project. The code is like this:

```
-(void)setTextureImage:(UIImage *)image {
  NSError *error;
  texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil error:&error];
  if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Error loading texture from image: %@",error);
  }
}

effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, self.textureCoordinates);
```

Now I want to repeat this texture on a rectangle. Is there any way use GLKit for this behavior? I've tried to use opengl function in addition to the glkit ones, but it raises errors:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name );
```

> 2011-11-09 20:10:28.614 ********[16309:207] GL ERROR: 0x0500
>
> 2011-11-09 20:10:30.840 ********[16309:207] Error loading texture from image: Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=8
>
> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 8.)" UserInfo=0x68545c0 {GLKTextureLoaderGLErrorKey=1280, GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=OpenGL error}

Comment: This has nothing to do with _wrapping_. The error seems to indicate a texture loading problem, not a texture wrapping problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit out-dated,
But you need to set `NSError *error;` to `NSError *error = nil;`
Already broke my head around this.

Answer (score 1):

Your images have to be powers of 2, you shouldn't call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D), and you need to call

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

after

```
[_baseEffect prepareToDraw];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever solved it, but this is what worked for me:

```
texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil error:&error];
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading texture from image: %@", error);
} else {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
}
```